# how to fetch monthly attendance report in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Everything is done successfully but only stuck with attendance report work.please help me

How to Fetch Data For monthly attendance report In Laravel 5.5

[image: This Is My Result]

Here Is My mysql Query

<-- language: lang-sql -->

```
$data = DB::table("attendance_management")->select('attendance_management.*',
        DB::raw('group_concat(attendance ORDER BY date) as atten'),
        DB::raw('group_concat(date ORDER BY date) as date_att')
    )->whereYear('date', '=', $year)
    ->whereMonth('date', '=', $month)
    ->groupBy('employee_name')
    ->orderBy('attendance_management.date', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

This is my Mysql Table

```
Date    client_id   Name   Attendance
01-05-18  34        Hitesh  Leave   
02-05-18  34        Hitesh  Leave   
03-05-18  34        Hitesh  Leave   
02-05-18  21        udip    Full-Day
01-05-18  21        udip    Full-Day
03-05-18  21        udip    Leave
```

This is View.blade.php

```
   @foreach($data as $data)
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
      <td>{{$data->shift}}</td>
      <td> {{$data->employee_name}} </td>
        <?php
        $dateaa = explode(',', $data->date_att);
        $attendance = explode(',', $data->atten);
        $daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month, $year);  
        for($i=1; $i<=$daysInMonth; $i++)
        {
         $db_date = $data->date;
         $resultDate = sprintf('%02d', $i);
         $date1 = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$resultDate;
         if($i==$db_date[2])
         {
           $x = 0;
           foreach($attendance as $key=>$value)
           {
             $x++;
             if($x==$key+1)
             {                                                   
                if($value=="Full-Day")
                {
                  $status = "P";
                  ?><td><?php echo $status; ?></td><?php
                }
                else
                {
                  $status = "A";
                  ?><td><?php echo $status; ?></td><?php
                }
              }
              else
              {
               //echo $x;
              }
          }
       }
       else
       {
          //echo $i;
       }
     }
     ?>
     <td> 25 </td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: If it was me, I'd leave the non-sql stuff out of it for the time being

Comment: I do not think you are going to find a person with enough time to salvage this code. I personally thought of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-72fz20wpQ) when I read the post. To be frank you need to reconsider using `for` instead of `foreach` and make nicer, ehm I mean readable, view code, so its clear for everyone not just you what it does. Regarding SQL, forget using raw sql if its hard to work with, use Eloquent all the way until you are 100% sure that its not possible. Good luck! (-1 for picture in the post).

Answer (score 0):

Use this library in your laravel by installing the package from github https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon . and use this code to get current month records

```
Attendance::whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))
            ->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))->get();
```